# RecyclerView with different widths

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to create RecyclerView with items which has always the same height but different width. It's quite easy with Horizontal Recycler View, but I want to do that with Vertical Recycler View.

The result should look like this:

```
 ___________________________________________
|                                           | 
|[................]  [......] [........]    |
|[......................]  [..............] |
|[.....]  [.................]               |
|[......................]  [......]         |
|                                           |
 -------------------------------------------
```

How can I achieve that? Or maybe there is something better than recycler view?

Comment: How can be this achieved on a horizontal RecyclerView? I'm looking for the same problem with no luck :(

Comment: Check [FlexboxLayoutManager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49973416/2299605)

Answer (score 4):

Using the approach suggested by Doron Yakovlev-Golani, I did it with this class:

```
public class LessonsLayoutManager extends StaggeredGridLayoutManager {

    private Point mMeasuredDimension = new Point();

    public LessonsLayoutManager() {
        super(2, HORIZONTAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state,
                          int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {

        final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec) - (getPaddingRight() + getPaddingLeft());

        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;
        int row = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {

            if (!measureScrapChild(recycler, i,
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                mMeasuredDimension)) continue;

            if (width + mMeasuredDimension.x > widthSize || mMeasuredDimension.x > widthSize) {
                row++;
                width = mMeasuredDimension.x;
            } else {
                width += mMeasuredDimension.x;
            }

            height += mMeasuredDimension.y;
        }

        setSpanCount(row);
        setMeasuredDimension(View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec), height);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollHorizontally() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically() {
        return false;
    }

    private boolean measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec, int heightSpec, Point measuredDimension) {

        View view = null;
        try {
            view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // try - catch is needed since support library version 24
        }

        if (view != null) {

            RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

            int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight(), p.width);
            int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(), p.height);

            view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);

            measuredDimension.set(
                view.getMeasuredWidth() + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin,
                view.getMeasuredHeight() + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin
            );

            recycler.recycleView(view);

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: This solution breaks on a java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero on file StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:931. This is intended to work with a variable number of columns per row or with a fixed number of columns?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is the [LayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html). It gives you a lot of options to do whatever layout you want in a RecyclerView. The layout you are describing seems to be a variant of what GridLayoutManager is providing, so perhaps start from there. You can see a solution to a similar problem in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681394/recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-trying-to-solve-wrap-content).