# Getting click on empty/whitespace of recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I need to show images in horizontal `RecyclerView`, and this `RecyclerView` is inside a row of `RecyclerView`. Now sometimes I receive 2 or 3 images and sometimes more that can fit in its width. So, i want it to be Scrollable when there are more items then its width and when it lists few items then i want empty area to be clickable as well. How can i achieve this behavior? 
**The problem i am having is concerned in first row where the area need to be clickable is not in my control.**[image]

Comment: what about `recyclerView.setOnClickListener`?

Comment: Use `setOnClickListener` on the ImageView within the ViewModel for your horizontal RecyclerViewAdapter.

Comment: using click listener on item works, but that don't gets triggered on empty space as that is not an item.

Comment: You have to add touch listener intend of onClick listener in recycleview

Comment: can't you have a `view` with `#00000000` as it's background?

Comment: @ashish i need to catch exact click behavior, not sure how can i get this with TouchListener by allowing user to scroll horizontally as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know, This is old question. But I was stumbled upon a similar scenario.

Place the recycler view inside card view (card view is actually a frame layout) and set the recycler view width to wrap_content instead of match_parent. and the card view (parent of the recycler) width to match_parent.  This will give you the expected result.

The card view is required, if you want to have the elevated cards for wrapping the recycler view. Otherwise any ViewGroup (like LinearLayout,Framelayout) should work.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a custom GridlayoutManager. Check this https://gist.github.com/ArthurSav/5f80e19d9ba6d562fbd5

[from Arthur's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32526403/703225)