# RecyclerView with horizontal GridLayoutManager adjusts its height to largest row

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, androidx, gridlayoutmanager

I want to use `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` to achieve something like that:

[image: Target]

Here is `GridLayoutManager` with horizontal orientation and 2 rows. What's important for me here is that `RecyclerView` is set as `wrap_content`.

So I tried to achieve my goal with such code:

`MainActivity.kt`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val adapter = Adapter()
    private val layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager

        adapter.submitList(listOf(Unit, Unit, Unit, Unit))
    }
}
```

`Adapter.kt`

```
class Adapter : ListAdapter<Any, ItemHolder>(DiffCallback()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(viewType, parent, false)
        return ItemHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemHolder, position: Int) {
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return when {
            position % 2 == 0 -> R.layout.item_small
            else -> R.layout.item_normal
        }
    }

    class DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Any>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Any, newItem: Any) = false
        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Any, newItem: Any) = false
    }

    class ItemHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
}
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`item_normal.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent" />
```

`item_small.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Unfortunately as the result, each row stretches to the largest row in grid:

[image: current]

The question is how can I remove the spacing between first row and second row? Keep in mind that I have to have scrollable horizontal grid that its height depends on its content. And items have to have fixed size.

Comment: See if [FlexboxLayoutManager](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout#flexboxlayoutmanager-within-recyclerview) will work for you.

Comment: I tried to play with flexbox demo, but I couldn't achieve horizontally scrollable view. Can you give any clue?

Comment: Here is a quick demo: Download the [FlexboxLayout project](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) and run the _demo-cat-gallery_ app. You will see a vertical scrolling gallery. Now, in _MainActivity.kt_ change `flexDirection = FlexDirection.ROW` to `flexDirection = FlexDirection.COLUMN` and run the app. You will now see a horizontal scroll of the same gallery. This is the idea.

Comment: I've checked that now, correct me if I'm wrong, but this would work I could specify height of the `RecyclerView`. With `FlexboxLayoutManager` I am unable to specify column count.

Comment: If you have design constraints that _FlexboxLayout_ can't accommodate then this isn't what will work for you.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34225902/4079010

Comment: I tried. It gives the same result like normal GridLayoutManager. Use sample I provided.

Comment: @Nominalista did u get it to work ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you know the ratios between heights of individual rows, you can try to use [`SpanSizeLookup`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup) to adjust height of each row. In your simple case, the smaller item (50dp) will take one row (span size 1) while the larger item (100dp) will take two rows (span size 2) so the whole grid overall will contain 3 rows.

Of course, for a more complex row configuration, the ratios might get a little more complicated: Say I wanted rows of heights 32dp/48dp/64dp, then the height ratios are 32/144, 48/144 and 64/144, which we can simplify to 2/9, 3/9, 4/9, getting 9 rows in total, with span sizes 2, 3, and 4 for individual items. In extreme cases, this can result in large number of rows (when the fractions cannot be simplified), but assuming you are using some type of grid (x8, x10, etc.) and the items are reasonably sized, it should still be manageable.

Anyway, in your case, the code would be this:

```
val layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 3, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
layoutManager.spanSizeLookup = object : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    override fun getSpanSize(position: Int) = when (position % 2) {
        0 -> 1 // 50dp item
        else -> 2 // 100dp item
    }
}
```

Given more rows, the `when` statement is going to get more complex, but if you already have the adapter at hand, you can use `getItemViewType` to differentiate individual rows in the `when` statement more easily.

If the number of item types is large or changes often (for example different item types on different screens), you can of course also implement the logic above in code, assuming you have access to the heights of the individual item types. Simply sum the heights to obtain the denominator and then find greatest common divisor of all heights and the sum to find the "simplification factor".

Comment: Seems very promising, I will check you solution asap.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use a [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html) to have different heights. Replace your `GridLayoutManager` with the below `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
```

[image]

Comment: Actually it's not working, because it adjust item width, not height, in horizontal `RecyclerView`.

Comment: @Nominalista Sorry i have made a mistake, need to set the orientation to `VERTICAL`. I updated my answer, have a look

Comment: Please notice that I mentioned in the description that it must be a horizontal recycler view. There are to many items in a real problem to fit in two columns.

Comment: Does the height of a row also change?

Comment: All items in a row have the same height. But they differ between other rows. I think in this case example above shows exactly how they look like.

Answer (score -1):

I think GridLayoutManager by default constraints the child views to be exactly same sizes.

I adjust the code to use a `LinearLayoutManager`, and the view for ViewHolder is to wrap two types views into a `RelativeLayout`.

See some code below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

RecyclerAdapter:

```java
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.item_normal,
                viewGroup,
                false
        );
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
```

And set LinearLayoutManager:

```java
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I made the sample simpler than the real problem. I have many rows in different configurations. So your solution doesn't apply here.